# powershell Set-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'NoNewline'

Tags: powershell

New to powershell and basically have plagiarize the following script to scan through a list of html files to remove unnecessary commas. I only get an error when running this on the server. Could use some suggestions or advice on how to fix. Here is the script.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\emailsigs -Filter *.htm |
  ForEach-Object {
    $oldContent = Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName
    $newContent = $oldContent -replace ' ,   &nbsp; ,   &nbsp; <br />'
    if ($newContent.Length -lt $oldContent.Length) { # was a replacement performed?
      Set-Content $_.FullName -NoNewline -Value $newContent
    }
  }
```

When I test this on my PC, it works. When I run this on the server hosting the html files, I adjust the file location:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\EmailSignatures -Filter *.htm |
  ForEach-Object {
    $oldContent = Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName
    $newContent = $oldContent -replace ' ,   &nbsp; ,   &nbsp; <br />'
    if ($newContent.Length -lt $oldContent.Length) { # was a replacement performed?
      Set-Content $_.FullName -NoNewline -Value $newContent
    }
  }
```

But I get the following error:

```
PS C:\_dev> C:\_dev\EsigCleanup_HTMV3.ps1
Set-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'NoNewline'.
At C:\_dev\EsigCleanup_HTMV3.ps1:6 char:31
+       Set-Content $_.FullName -NoNewline -Value $newContent
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

Comment: It's probably completely unrelated to your problem, but if your file path contains [ or ] characters, you will get this message. Swithching to -LiteralPath made it go away (yes, really...)

Answer (score 2):

Are the server and your PC running the same version of PowerShell (check $PSversionTable)? NoNewLine was added in PowerShell 5.0.

Edit: there is an extremely detailed answer on StackOverflow that addresses options for lower versions of PowerShell - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279848/prevent-trailing-newline-in-powershell-out-file-command .